# XCode cannot build app when trying to use NSViewRepresentable in MacOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am trying to use `NSViewRepresentable` in my MacOS app but as soon as I do the build fails and I cannot preview my app in Xcode. The error log info I am getting is -> `Application Specific Information: dyld [ Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI19NSViewRepresentableP14_layoutOptionsyAA013_PlatformViewd6LayoutF0V0C4TypeQzFZTq..`

It seems that `NSViewRepresentable` is not being found in my project. How can I fix this? Using XCode and CLT versions 14.1 on MacOS Ventura. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MyView: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> some NSView {
        NSTextField(string: "Hello")
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `import SwiftUI`?

Comment: Yes I did, for some reason it still doesnt work.

Comment: Consider adding more detail about your code then.

Comment: Right! I added it in the question, thanks.

Comment: Did you try importing the AppKit framework? NSViewRepresentable allows you to use AppKit views in SwiftUI apps so you may need to import AppKit to use NSViewRepresentable.